# Appropriate weights to obtain chi squared goodness of fit

Tags: regression, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

I have a set of observed ($X$) and theoretical ($Y$) data of length $N$:

$$X:\{x_1\pm \sigma_{x1}, x_2\pm \sigma_{x2}, ..., x_N\pm \sigma_{xN}\}\\ Y:\{y_1\pm \sigma_{y1}, y_2\pm \sigma_{y2}, ..., y_N\pm \sigma_{yN}\}$$

I know that their relationship is linear, and I need to find the best fit $(a, b)$ parameters for $y = a x + b$. I use [ODR (the scipy implementation)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html) which, as far as I understand, can handle both sets of uncertainties unlike OLS which only takes uncertainties in $X$ into account.

After the fitting is done, i.e.: I have the best fit values and their standard deviations $(a\pm\sigma_a, b\pm\sigma_b)$, I want to obtain a goodness of fit measure. Following [Bevington & Robinson](http://www.agapea.com/libros/Data-Reduction-and-Error-Analysis-for-the-Physical-Sciences-9780072472271-i.htm) I know that the reduced chi squared follows:

$$\chi^2_\nu=\frac{1}{N-2}\sum\frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}[y_i-y(x_i)]^2$$

where $y(x_i)=ax_i+b$ and $\sigma_i^2$ should be "*the variance that describes the uncertainties in each point*". This is where I get lost. How should I calculate $\sigma_i^2$? I can think of several ways:

1. $\sigma_i^2 = \sigma_{xi}^2$ (use uncertainty in $X$)
2. $\sigma_i^2 = \sigma_{yi}^2$ (use uncertainty in $Y$)
3. $\sigma_i^2 = \sigma_{xi}^2 + \sigma_{yi}^2$  (combine uncertainties in quadrature)
4. $\sigma_i^2 = (\sigma_{xi} + \sigma_{yi})^2$  (combine uncertainties)
5. $\sigma_i^2 = \sigma_{a}^2 x_i^2 + \sigma_{xi}^2 a^2 + \sigma_{b}^2$ (uncertainty for $y(x_i)$)

I could probably come up with some more, but you get the point. Which one is the correct variance (weight) to use here, and why?